# Got this error during ghostnet deployment, "No case matched: At /kind, unexpected string instead of endorsement"

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, origination

I tried to originate a smart contract using smartpy ide and this is the error what I am getting.
[image]

An update on this
I tried commenting all the sp.emit() in the code and deployed. Then it was working fine.

Anyone who can explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sp.emit(), spaces should not be given on tag.
sp.emit(tag="eventGenerated")
if you are giving space, then there will be an issue.

Comment: Thanks @Kin this was really helpful.

Comment: Please mark your problem as resolved with the answer resolving your problem.